# Unexpected token when running grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to execute the following command `grunt build` but when trying it the below error message appear

```
PS C:\Users\EDMA\Documents\Tutenlabs\Bitbucket\tuten-macarena-backoffice-web> grunt build
C:\Users\EDMA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.16.0\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:44
    let isMatch = picomatch(String(patterns[i]), { ...options, onResult }, true);
                                                   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EDMA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.16.0\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\findup-sync\index.js:12:10)
```

I navigate to `C:\Users\EDMA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.16.0\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:44` path and looked for **index.js** file to check whether there's an error or not, but the strange thing is there isn't. Any idea what's going on here?

Aditionally, this is AngularJS.

Comment: @Eduardojis you may need to check `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` and `babel-polyfill`

Comment: I just checked the "babel-plugin-transform-runtime" and "babel-polyfill" but there is no babel plugin or dependencies in the package.json. should them be there?

Comment: @Eduardojis you can check this [package](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel) and try using it.

Comment: Spreading Object literals , _(i.e. this part `{ ...options, ... }` in the error log)_, is fully supported in nodejs version `>=8.3.1` according to this [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility). Which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: This project is running on nodejs version 6.16.0, probably that's the error. But I can't use a further version of 6.16.0 because at first this project was developed on 6.16.0 version, so when I use for example nodejs 12.10.0 version it compiles with errors. So let me try at least using >=8.3.1 version to see what happens hahaha. Thanks a lot